# 3 or 2 column layout depends on actual content

Tags: html, css, layout, autosize

I have to build almost standard 3 columns layout

`-----header-----`
`-s1-content-s2--`
`-----footer-----`

Where sidebar1 and 2 has `width:25%` and content box has 50%. And it working perfect.

But the difference is in sidebar1. On some subpages there is absolutely no content for it. I set css for sidebar1 to `max-width:25%;` and when no content appears div has 0px x 0px. So almost done.

The final effect is to stretch content div to 75% when sidebar1 is empty.

Is it possible to do this without ugly css hacks or using JS? I checked many solutions and most are not working correctly.

Comment: ugly css hacks?? it's not vudu here css is css.

Comment: have you tried not assigning a width to the center column?  Make sure the other two have widths or at least the second one and see if it fills the space when the first one is 0 width. EDIT: actually that will only work if you are using a table or css display:table et. al. Be nice if you could include any markup and css you already have.  If you want to be really helpful to us, put it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: In my opinion ugly css hacks is for example set another wrapper for content and sidebar2 just to mess with code readability.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I tried but it appear on full size just like header or footer and leave sidebars above and under...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This handles optional content on the left or right.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/693tv/)

**HTML**

```
<header></header>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-sidebar">
        Optional Content
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>To sailors, oaths are household words; they will swear in the trance of the calm, and in the teeth of the tempest; they will imprecate curses from the topsail-yard-arms, when most they teeter over to a seething sea; but in all my voyagings, seldom have I heard a common oath when God's burning finger has been laid on the ship; when His "Mene, Mene, Tekel Upharsin" has been woven into the shrouds and the cordage.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right-sidebar">
        Optional Content
    </div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
}

#left-sidebar, #content, #right-sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

header, footer {
    background: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
}

#content {
}

#left-sidebar {
    background: lime;
    max-width: 25%;
}

#right-sidebar {
    background: red;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @KamilKrzes - I Gotta say, I'm kind of annoyed. I posted this exact same code 6 minutes earlier than this answer. Then you unaccepted my answer for this one. Why are you saying this answer is correct and mine isn't?

Comment: @Adam If it helps. I did not copy content from your answer. I didn't even see it until I had posted my answer.

Comment: @screenmutt - I know you didn't. I just don't understand why my answer was originally accepted when it contains the exact same code as this one.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use either `float`s, or `display: table`, I prefer using the latter, but to each their own.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-one">
        some (or no) content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        main content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-two">
        sidebar two
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper { display: table; }
#wrapper>div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
#wrapper .sidebar-one { max-width: 25%; }
#wrapper .sidebar-two { width: 25%; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first I try to put code into fiddle and it worked. In my not so I started to search. This goes wrong cause of top level wrapper with float:left. Well I hate working on somebody messed up projects. Especially layouts.

Comment: @KamilKrzes - so take `float: left` off the top level wrapper. Why would you `float: left` something that is designed to be the full width of the screen?